# I need to show the date field of a merge in the invoice model, specifically in the date_invoice field of the invoice model

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I have this module in which I have created the date field, this date field I want that when I finish compiling the invoices it is added as the date of the invoice. In the invoice model, date_invoice field

```
for rec in (active_records - rec_to_exclude):
            for line in rec.invoice_line_ids:
                same_line = InvLine.search([
                    ('invoice_id', '=', new_rec_id.id),
                    ('product_id','=',line.product_id.id),
                    ('price_unit','=',line.price_unit),
                    ('discount','=',line.discount),
                    #('invoice_line_tax_ids','in',line.invoice_line_tax_ids.ids),
                ], limit=1)
                if same_line:
                    same_line.quantity += line.quantity
                else:
                    InvLine.create({
                        'product_id': line.product_id and line.product_id.id or False,
                        'quantity' : line.quantity,
                        'uom_id' : line.uom_id.id,
                        'price_unit' : line.price_unit,
                        'invoice_id': new_rec_id.id,
                        'name': line.name,
                        'discount': line.discount,
                        'account_id': line.account_id.id,
                        'invoice_date_invoice': self.date_invoicea,
                        'invoice_line_tax_ids': [(6,0, line.invoice_line_tax_ids.ids)]
                    })
                    for record in self:
                        record[(date_invoice)] = record(date_invoicea)
```

I have tried several functions, but it has not worked.